# Type 'GameScene has no member 'delay'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, swift3

I declared delay and it is giving me an error, I am trying to slow down the timer.

```
//Updates Timer
    func updateTimer() {
        var delay: Int
        seconds  += 1
        self.timerLabel.text = String(self.seconds * 0.01)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(-2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.delay), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oKX8b.png here is the image

Comment: Please include the error as a text here, so that the question is still useful even if that image gets removed.

Comment: I think you are in a wrong way. First of all your delay is a var and no a function, second point, in sprite kit you should avoid to use NSTimer except for NSNotification in waiting game

Comment: Where is the delay function

Answer (score 0):

the selector portion of a NSTimer is meant to run a function so you declare the function then the timer should be placed outside of the function instead of inside the function

```
func updateTimer() {
    var delay: Int
    seconds  += 1
    self.timerLabel.text = String(self.seconds * 0.01)}
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

also could you be more specific when you say you are trying to slow down the timer so

Comment: When I put this in it did not solve anything. It had just given me more errors.

Comment: what version of swift are you in 2.2 or 3.0 currently

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that there is no selector for `GameScene.delay`. You need a func that matches this name. Note that because you have used "GameScene" rather than "gameScene", it may be a class, in which case you would need a "class func" called delay. However, more likely is you would want "self.delay" to be called. ie. one of

```
    func delay(timer: NSTimer) { ... }
    class func delay(timer: NSTimer) { ... }
```

Also, what are you trying to achieve with "-2.0"? You can't run a timer in the past - if will default to 0.1 if <= 0.

Comment: You should not be using the instance name inside of the selector,  the `target` field specifies which instance to fire on,  you use `#selector(GameScene.updateTimer)` for your own personal note,  but the default namespace is not even needed  as long as some namespace is provided (If you made some other class that was not an SKScene, and had an updateTimer method, it would still call the proper method from the target